# How to color alignment visualization?

Tags: python, alignment, visualization

[image: I was able to draw this alignment, but I want it to be colored]

I have got the code from this website(https://dmnfarrell.github.io/bioinformatics/bokeh-sequence-aligner)
but, when I write this line (colors = get_colors(seqs)), an error occurs that get_colors is not defined.

```
from PIL import Image 
import os, io, random
import string
import numpy as np

from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Align import MultipleSeqAlignment
from Bio import AlignIO, SeqIO
import panel as on
import panel.widgets as pnw
pn.extension()
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Plot, Grid, Range1d
from bokeh.models.glyphs import Text, Rect
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
def view_alignment(aln, fontsize="9pt", plot_width=800):

 seqs = [rec.seq for rec in (aln)]
 ids = [rec.id for rec in aln]    

text = [i for s in list(seqs) for i in s]
N = len(seqs[0])
S = len(seqs)    
width = .4

x = np.arange(1,N+1)
y = np.arange(0,S,1)
#creates a 2D grid of coords from the 1D arrays
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
#flattens the arrays
gx = xx.ravel()
gy = yy.flatten()
#use recty for rect coords with an offset
recty = gy+.5
h= 1/S
#now we can create the ColumnDataSource with all the arrays
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=gx, y=gy, recty=recty, text=text))
plot_height = len(seqs)*15+50
x_range = Range1d(0,N+1, bounds='auto')
if N>100:
    viewlen=100
else:
    viewlen=N
#view_range is for the close up view
view_range = (0,viewlen)
tools="xpan, xwheel_zoom, reset, save"

#entire sequence view (no text, with zoom)
p = figure(title=None, plot_width= plot_width, plot_height=50,
           x_range=x_range, y_range=(0,S), tools=tools,
           min_border=0, toolbar_location='below')
rects = Rect(x="x", y="recty",  width=1, height=1, 
 fill_color="colors",
             line_color=None, fill_alpha=0.6)
p.add_glyph(source, rects)
p.yaxis.visible = False
p.grid.visible = False  

#sequence text view with ability to scroll along x axis
p1 = figure(title=None, plot_width=plot_width, 
plot_height=plot_height,
            x_range=view_range, y_range=ids, tools="xpan,reset",
            min_border=0, toolbar_location='below')#, lod_factor=1)          
glyph = Text(x="x", y="y", text="text", 
text_align='center',text_color="black",
            text_font="monospace",text_font_size=fontsize)
rects = Rect(x="x", y="recty",  width=1, height=1, 
fill_color="color",
            line_color=None, fill_alpha=0.4)
p1.add_glyph(source, glyph)
p1.add_glyph(source, rects)

p1.grid.visible = False
p1.xaxis.major_label_text_font_style = "bold"
p1.yaxis.minor_tick_line_width = 0
p1.yaxis.major_tick_line_width = 0

p = gridplot([[p],[p1]], toolbar_location='below')

return p
```

That is why I removed grt_colors() line, but I want another way for coloring the visualization.

Comment: edit your question and add some of your code here. get_colors is not defined cause you didnt add it to your program

Comment: @lolc I removed it because it gave me error.

Comment: @NourHany Did you copy the helper functions? They are explained below. So the NotImplementedError can be avoided, I think.